# Use of present participle

Tags: sentence-construction

> The boy is the son of the man standing here.

In the above sentence we used the participle form 'standing' after the object instead of the noun.
Is the sentence correct? And if it is correct, what does it mean?

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is correct and it simply means that you are pointing to a boy, whose father is standing here.
The sentence could be made clearer though, by using "who",

> The boy is the son of the man, who is standing here.

Comment: I also thought that. But I am confused that the sentence means that a man is standing here and the boy is his son. I saw the meaning in the English to bengali dictionary and I got the confusing answer. That's why I asked.

Comment: Usually the dictionaries provide literal meanings to words of foreign languages, but the real meaning might differ, as it depends a lot on the way the sentence is written, and not just the words that have been used.

Comment: The writer is talking about a boy. He is describing the boy, not his father. He just is telling that this boy is the son of a man, and that man is standing here.

Comment: Note that the sentence doesn't say anything about the boy being present. If you're pointing to anyone at all (in a literal sense), you're pointing to the man who is the boy's father. Rather than say *pointing to* I might just say *describing*.